# Display main page when an error occurs

Tags: flask, error-handling, wsgi, http-error

The application consists of only one page.
Instead of error pages it should simple display the main site.
How should I implement the error handles for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of `error handlers`

i.e)

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('base.html'), 404
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want to handle **all** errors and not just page not found.

Comment: Please read the common error codes [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/errorpages/#common-error-codes)

Comment: But also you can extend this to other error code as well. Look at this [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/exceptions/#custom-errors)

Comment: It's upto you to decide. And there is no other way to catch all the exception at once and display in to the main page. Well from my knowledge...